# Fabricjs canvas size best practices?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabricjs in my project. What is the best practice for setting canvas size? In my case, the canvas should not be larger than 500x500. This is the maximum size. But if I upload an image as a background, the canvas should be proportional to the original image, but no larger than 500x500. How to do it right?
Besides, I want the image to have the dimensions of the original background size when saving.

I am currently using this technique:

```
const EDITOR_MAX_WIDTH = 500;
const EDITOR_MAX_HEIGHT = 500;

fabric.Image.fromURL(uploadedFile, (img) => {
        const scale = Math.min(
        EDITOR_MAX_WIDTH / img.width,
        EDITOR_MAX_HEIGHT / img.height
      );
      editor.canvas.setDimensions({
        width: img.width,
        height: img.height,
      });
      editor.canvas.setDimensions(
        {
          width: `${img.width * scale}px`,
          height: `${img.height * scale}px`,
        },
        { cssOnly: true }
      );
      editor.canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
      editor.canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The second call to `setDimensions` seems redundant to me.

Checkout `fabric.util.scaleToFit`.

Did you consider leaving the canvas dims 500*500 and making the background transparent?